# How to get different height html divs to float up

Tags: html, css

I've got a series of dynamically created divs of varying heights in a container div.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id='d1'>Varying text...</div>
  <div id='d2'>Varying text...</div>
  <div id='d3'>Varying text...</div>
  <div id='d4'>Varying text...</div>
  <div id='d5'>Varying text...</div>
  <div id='d6'>Varying text...</div>
  <div id='d7'>Varying text...</div>
</div>
```

[image: flow.jpg]

When I "float: left" the divs wrap as expected leaving white space between the shorter divs and the next row of divs.

[image: flow2.jpg]

How would I get the divs to effectively "float: up", wrapping veritcally rather than horizonatally.  Using only css.

Ideally, item 2 would be under item 1 but any improvement would help.

So it would end up looking like this

[image]

Comment: So would the intended outcome be 1234567 ? Lined vertically ?

Comment: Give us an image of how you would want them to show..

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Cgz93/

Comment: Or this? http://jsfiddle.net/Cgz93/1/ (I'm really not sure.)

Comment: Nice fiddle Jared!  I just edited post to show the layout I'm looking for.  A single column could have many blocks as long at the total height didn't surpass the height of the container.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using jQuery Masonry. It could be a great fix for this.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Or try Isotope, which has much better performance

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Wow, this looks perfect.  I hope the learning curve isn't to steep.  thx!

Comment: can't we do with out using a jquery plugin. Because my web page is facing several issues like lazy loading and performance related. I used masonry but it doesn't seem to work in IE8.

Comment: @Ramaraju.d try [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) it has way better performance

Answer (score 3):

If you want the divs to stack vertically in all browser agents, you'll need to wrap each 'section' in a containing element. Here's an example of what I mean.

**the css**

```
// let's reset our elements
.site-container,
.element-container,
.my-element {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.site-container {
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* centers your site container on the page */
    clear: both; /* basic float clearing */
}
.element-container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 300px; /* we'll have 3 sections width 10px spacing */
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.element-container.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.my-element {
    width: 280px; /* 300 - 20px [total padding] = 280px */
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* add a bottom margin */
    padding: 10px; /* makes our element 320px wide */
}

// make background-color classes
.bg-red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.bg-blue {
    background-color: #3b8acd;
}
```

**the markup**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Vertical boxes!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="site-container">

        <div class="element-container">
            <div class="my-element bg-red">
                1
            </div>

            <div class="my-element bg-blue">
                2
            </div>
        </div><!-- /element-container -->

        <div class="element-container">
            <div class="my-element bg-blue">
                3
            </div>

            <div class="my-element bg-red">
                4
            </div>
        </div><!-- /element-container -->

        <div class="element-container last">
            <div class="my-element bg-red">
                5
            </div>

            <div class="my-element bg-blue">
                6
            </div>
        </div><!-- /element-container -->

    </div><!-- /site-container -->    
</body>
</html>
```

As far as the seventh div you have, I would suggest making it span across the entire site-container. It's aesthetically pleasing :)

Comment: yeah, that makes sense but because the blocks are of text of varying length I don't know how many will fit in a given height.  So I'm looking for a way for them to "flow" to the next column.  html does this so well horizontally, but seems to be missing key functions to do it vertically.

Answer (score 2):

You should try placing each column of div's into it's own container, and float them left. For example:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='col1'>
        <div id='d1'>asdf</div>
        <div id='d2'>asdf</div>
    </div>
    <div id='col2'>
        <div id='d3'>asdf</div>
        <div id='d4'>asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

etc, etc.

each column floats left against one another and each item in the columns flows vertically quite well... here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/V6z8F/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't know how tall the inner divs are so I don't know how many will fit in a given column

Answer (score 1):

Recently I did this for my project.

Add CSS for the parent class:

```
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-count: 4;
column-count: 4;
```

#### Example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives to Masonry that work very well:

**Salvattore** (CSS driven): http://salvattore.com/

**Isotope**: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html