# how to vertically align HTML object to cover page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have about 10 or more objects, with same width but different height. I want to put them like the below image, to fully cover the page. Here is what i've done but it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/mhmdshv/e0xvcgnw/

HTML:

```
<div id="book">
<div class="book" style="height:310px; width:200px">...</div>
<div class="book" style="height:100px; width:200px">...</div>
<div class="book" style="height:500px; width:200px">...</div>
<div class="book" style="height:400px; width:200px">...</div>
 <div class="book" style="height:150px; width:200px">...</div>
<div class="book"style="height:200px; width:200px">...</div>
<div class="book" style="height:40px; width:200px">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
   body{padding:25px;}
#book{text-align:center;outline:5px solid aqua;}
.book{
    display:inline-block;

    border:1px dotted silver;background-color:pink;margin:9px;text-align:center;
}
```

There is a gap between objects that don't have same height... i want it to be gone. Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: take a look at css `columns`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e0xvcgnw/1/)

I added 2 divs,

```
.left{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
.right{
    float:left;
    margin-left:18px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly... But unfortunately i have no access to objects. I can't put them in different divisions because i use wordpress and it automatically publishes the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy there is no css way to achiefe it without manipulating the dom. In your case you can add columns "left" and "right" to structure the elements to avoid the gab.

You also can use comon plugins like [MASONRY](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Also have a look at this answers:

[How to get different height html divs to float up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7465560/2667584)

[CSS Floating Divs At Variable Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5234749/2667584)

Answer (score 0):

Try to discover css3 **column** property.
Maybe this source will help you:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Answer (score 0):

Using [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) created this:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#book');
var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
    // options
    columnWidth: 100,
    itemSelector: '.book',
    margin: 0 auto;
});
```

```css
body {
    padding:25px;
}
#book {
    text-align:center;
    outline:5px solid aqua;
}
.book {
    width: 45%;
    border:1px dotted silver;
    background-color:pink;
    margin:9px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div id="book" class="js-masonry">
    <div class="book" style="height:310px;">...</div>
    <div class="book" style="height:100px;">...</div>
    <div class="book" style="height:500px;">...</div>
    <div class="book" style="height:400px;">...</div>
    <div class="book" style="height:150px;">...</div>
    <div class="book" style="height:200px;">...</div>
    <div class="book" style="height:40px;">...</div>
</div>
```